# Solving Kronecker-structured linear equations

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I need to approximately solve the following underdetermined system of $n$ linear equations

$$y_i=a_i^T X b_i$$

Where $X$ is $d\times d$ unknown matrix, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are given vectors and $n=d$. Is there a way to do this much faster than vectorizing both sides of each equation and calling `LinearSolve`?

LinearSolve approach destroys the structure, it reduces to solving a system with $d^3$ coefficients instead of original one with $2d^2$ coefficients.

Below is an example of this approach, it's too slow for my application where $d=1000$. On that scale, `backward` is 2000x slower than `forward`, with majority of the time spent in `LinearSolve`. I was hoping for 100x slower since that seems like typical `LinearSolve` overhead for unstructured systems on that scale.

```
n = d = 50;
{a, b} = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, d}], {2}];
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
forward[X_] := MapThread[#1.X.#2 &, {a, b}];
y = forward[X];

backward[Y_] := 
  With[{mat = MapThread[Flatten@Outer[Times, #1, #2] &, {a, b}]},
   x = LinearSolve[mat, y];
   ArrayReshape[x, {d, d}]
   ];
Print["forward time is ", forward[X]; // Timing // First];
{timing, error} = Timing[Norm[forward[backward[y]] - y, Infinity]];
Print["backward time is ", timing];
Print["error is ", error]
```

Comment: That’s for one equation, and we have n=d of them

Comment: If you have only $d$ equations and you are solving an underdetermined system of equations you may want to specify additional constraints on $X$. If $X$ should be minimized, look for a pseudo-inverse of a direct product...

Comment: That what `LinearSolve` seems to do in this case, gives identical solution to `LeastSquares`